# Double Installed Geopandas

Tags: python, installation, geopandas

I installed geopandas using pip install but I didn't know about the dependencies not working so I used conda-forge to download it but I didn't uninstall first. This is the mistake I know.

Now the whole notebook is broken essentially. I can't use geopandas. If I use urllib the kernel dies and it must restart, but never runs.

When I use sys module it says false, but when I use conda list it shows up. Also, it takes hours to do anything in the terminal as the list of packages that are inconsistent is long.

I also tried the revisions method but it says this
"RemoveError: 'requests' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment."

Everything worked well prior to the install conda-forge geopandas line that you can find on their documentation. Please Help!

Comment: You might have to remove that conda environment and start over.

Comment: I made a new one, but the issue was in my root environment so when I made another and tried to add packages like even basic NumPy it would give me an error

Comment: If this is an option, I would remove your conda installation and [re-install miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). In the future, I would recommend creating environments and installing into them (instead of installing into the base environment). It is much easier to remove one env and recreate it than to fix the base environment. I've had to remove my miniconda installation several times before learning this lesson :)